# Passing default data to Vue form component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Here is a simple Vue 2.0 form component. It consists of a number input and a button, e.g.:

[image]

Note that the value of the input is tied to the component's `data` using `v-model`. `buttonText` is passed in as a prop.

**What's the best way to pass a default value into the form**, so that it initially renders with a value other than 10?

- Using `props` doesn't seem to be the right way to do it because then `v-model` no longer works properly.
- However, `data` can't be passed in the way props can, as far as I can tell from Vue documentation.

.

```
<template>
    <form v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit">
      <input v-model="amount" type="number" min="1" max="20"></input>
      <button type="submit">{{ buttonText }}</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: [ 'buttonText' ],
    data: function() {
      return {
        amount: 10
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onSubmit: function() {
        this.$emit("submit", parseInt(this.amount) );
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You can use props. It won't give any issue.

Comment: @SureshVelusamy No, you can't. Vue throws a warning that you shouldn't be editing props because they will be overwritten if the parent component is re-rendered.

Comment: Yep . As #vuejs says we can use computed property :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass in a prop (say `initialAmount`) and reference that when initializing the `amount` value in the data function:

```
export default {
  props: {
    buttonText: { type: String },
    initialAmount: { type: Number, default: 10 },
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      amount: this.initialAmount
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit: function() {
      this.$emit("submit", parseInt(this.amount) );
    }
  }
}
```